# XSD element is not expected in GML validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, gml

Despite some exaples with similar problem as mine, none of them explain my problem:

The text of my error in validation is:

`ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element '{urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0}OT_BUSP_A': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}AbstractFeature, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}DynamicFeature, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}DynamicFeatureCollection, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}MultiPointCoverage, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}MultiCurveCoverage, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}MultiSurfaceCoverage, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}MultiSolidCoverage, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}GridCoverage, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}RectifiedGridCoverage, {http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}Observation )`

XML looks that:

```
<gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mz="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:mapaZasadnicza:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:bt="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
xmlns:ot="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0" gml:id="GUGiK_OT_BUSP_A" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0 ../XSD/OT_BDOT10k_BDOO.xsd">
```

As you can see the one of expected line: "xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" exist, but maybe with wrong prefix

XSD (OT_BDOT10k_BDOO) looks that:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ot="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:bt="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" targetNamespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" schemaLocation="BT_ModelPodstawowy.xsd"/>
    <include schemaLocation="OT_BDOT10k_Slowniki.xsd">
```

I attach the headings of rest mention .xsd's file hee, so:
BT_ModelPodstawowy.xsd has got

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:bt="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" xmlns:mz="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:mapaZasadnicza:1.0" targetNamespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/citation.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:mapaZasadnicza:1.0" schemaLocation="MZ_MapaZasadnicza.xsd"/>
```

MZ_MapaZasadnicza.xsd start that:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:mz="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:mapaZasadnicza:1.0" xmlns:bt="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" targetNamespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:mapaZasadnicza:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" schemaLocation="BT_ModelPodstawowy.xsd"/>
```

and finally OT_BDOT10k_Slowniki.xsd:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ot="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:bt="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" targetNamespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:bazaDanychObiektowTopograficznych10k:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="urn:gugik:specyfikacje:gmlas:modelPodstawowy:1.0" schemaLocation="BT_ModelPodstawowy.xsd"/>
```

Maybe is connect with gml (Geographic Markup Languange), but I'm not sure which prefix and how to replace it.

Thanks for every kind of help!

Comment: There's not enough information in your post to determine the origin of the issue. Seems like a schema validation error. Maybe try posting more of the XML?

Comment: Problem solved. I had a wrong version of xml files (1.0 not 2.0) like xsd need.
Chef check it and sent me next xmls with new, correct heading